# Is there a way to write an API in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

Is there a way in AngularJS to write an API. Actually I need to load an HTML page in my application (AngularJS and Java) based on a external web request.

When I do this from a server-side web API like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public ModelAndView apiTest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Request comming from outside");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    System.out.println("Api session"+session.getId());
    ModelAndView newModel = null;
    newModel = new ModelAndView("somepage.html");
    return loginModel;
}
```

The above code loads the page, but on the request browser i.e. from where the API was called. In turn I want the page to load on the current running application.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where are your `HTML` files located ?

Comment: on the server where i have written the java API

Comment: One workaround is moving those HTML files in client side, let's say `templates` folder 
and you can get the `HTML` as `$http.get('templates/somepage.html').then(function(response){//response.data contains your HTML file's content})`

Then you can manipulate the raw HTML content using ng-bind-html inside a page.

Comment: Do you mean: can angular consume html *from an API*?

Comment: let me be more clear on my question (forget about the angular API mentioned in question), i have an application using (angular and java) and a user is login to the application. now whenever somebody hits the particular API(url from outside)  i want to load an html page on the user side which is login to the application not on the side who is hitting the api

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes

Comment: Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Eeq1aXdhVAzwTKNrgz0S?p=preview) on two different types of HTML content loading in an Angular application.

1) Using `ng-include` where we provide HTML file url path and ask angular to go and fetch the html contents to load in particular DOM.

2) Using `ng-bind-html` where we can send our html content from an API through a server call and load it in our DOM as html(which is OP's scenario).

In the example we request two html templates and load in our DOM in two different ways one template is loaded by setting scope variable with a html file path which `ng-include` in turn uses to load that html content.

In second case we request another html through `$http GET` call and get template content in data and assign it to a scope variable and then `ng-bind-html` will convert that string into an actual HTML content.

Below is sample code in JS

```
 $scope.requestHTML = function(reqstType) {

                if (reqstType === 'server') {
                    $scope.reqstType = 'server';
                    $http.get('dummy.html').success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        $scope.htmldata = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
                    }).error(function(res) {
                        alert('request Failed Idiot !!');
                    });
                } else if (reqstType === 'client') {
                    $scope.reqstType = 'client';
                    $scope.contentURL = 'load.html';
                }
            };
```

In HTML

```
<div> 
        <button ng-click="requestHTML('client')"> Request Client HTML </button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <br> 
         <button ng-click="requestHTML('server')"> Request Server HTML</button>
       </div>
        <div ng-include="contentURL"> </div>

        <div ng-bind-html="htmldata"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using `ngResource`. This is angular whay which lets you interact with *RESTful* server-side data sources. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you can read more about it. Here is a small demonstration how it can be used:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('apiService', apiService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function apiService($resource) {
        var api = {};
        api.file = {
            getSomeFile: $resource('http://example.com/api/:file', {id: '@file'}, {
                get: {
                     method: 'GET',
                     params: {
                         getFooter: true
                     }
                }
            })
        }
        return api;
    }

})();
```

This is just of example how `ngResource` could be used. You'll be using this factory (service) as a normal factory you would inject in your page controller or wherever you want and would call `getSomeFile` when you'll be needing that HTML file to be included.